# Standard USB C Power Supply and Overclocking

Tags: pi-4, power-supply

Is the standard (official) raspberry pi usb c power supply able to reliably supply a raspberry pi 400 with overclocked cpu and gpu?
Meaning so that the pi gets enough watts to run at maximum speed continuously.

Reading the Ampere specs it seems to not have that much head room compared to the specs for the pi.
But what are your experiences with the actual hardware?

Comment: your 2nd question is opinion based ... it is off topic here

Comment: please add the information about power requirements of an overclocked RPi

Comment: IIRC the official power supply is 3A while the pi normally draws a bit more than 1A. However, overclocking the Pi4 is greatly discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - the "official" RPi power supply is capable of providing enough power. However, overclocking the RPi is not a reliable mode of operation for several reasons - all of which come back to the fact that several aspects of the RPi 4 design are ***marginal***.

If you want a second opinion, and some actual experiences, [this article](https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/how-to-overclock-raspberry-pi-4) - from the "official" RPi magazine last year - corroborates the un-reliability, and documents *some* of the issues. Overclocking the RPi 400 is likely to be even less reliable than described here since it is in an enclosure that will limit airflow.